# How do I get jQuery .attr to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

So I'm making a photo frame. You can find it here: http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2. It's built using SVG. I'm trying to change the frame's background color when a button is clicked. I've read that .addClass and .removeClass won't work. I stumbled across .attr and I'm trying to use it. Here is the thing I'm trying to change.

```
<rect class="border" x="77.9" y="78.7" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1100" height="600"/>
```

And the button...

```
 <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

The CSS...

```
.border {
fill:#1E3868;
```

}

```
.red {
fill:#FF0000;
```

}

and the jQuery...

```
$(document).ready (function() {
('#button').click (function() {
        $(".border").attr("fill", "red");
});
```

});

I've also linked to this in my HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: Not sure why you are saying that `addClass`and `removeClass` won't work, they do. However: 1. you're missing a `$` in `$('#button')`, 2. you're using `#border` when you should be using `.border` (or use `id="border"` instead of `class="border"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think because that is a `css` property ypu can use like bellow

```
$(".border").css("fill", "red");
```

The full script for this

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#button').click (function() {
        $(".border").css("fill", "red");
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready (function() {
$('#button').click (function() {
        $(".border").css("fill", "red");
});

Comment: @OwenMelbourne I just added the line which could be reason of problem, shoud I update with full code.

Comment: Look at the example @Mritunjay posted in his answer, replace yours with this, and see if it works to your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass`and `removeClass`. But inline attributes or styles will override those set via CSS, you were missing a `$`, and mixing up `.class` and `#id` selectors.

Updated HTML:

```
<svg>
    <rect id="therect" class="border" x="77.9" y="78.7" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10" width="1100" height="400"/>
</svg>
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

CSS:

```
.border {
    fill:#1E3868;
}

.red {
    fill:#FF0000;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#button').click (function() {
    $("#therect").removeClass("border").addClass("red");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zkv3e4jr/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#button').click (function() {
        $(".border").css("fill", "red");
    });
});
```

as Mritunjay said - treat it as a css property - this seems to work in Chrome.